# Active Directory Not Being Recognized on Client PC

Tags: active-directory

I have a newly configured server with Windows Server 2012 on which I have added the Active Directory Domain Services to and created a new forest with a single domain tree.  I also have a newly configured Windows 8 Professional box on the same network (2 switches, 1 wireless router that connects directly to a cable modem) and when I attempt to add the computer to the domain, it says that it cannot find or locate the Domain Controller for my domain.  I tried this on a Windows 7 Ultimate box and it gave more information but basically related to DNS issues.  Is there something special I need to do on the server or on the wireless router (DHCP) to allow my client PC's to find my AD server?

Comment: I just changed the DNS settings on my client PC to the primary being the AD server and it was able to join the domain.  What can I do to my wireless router so that these settings can stay at automatic?

Comment: Configure your wireless router to hand out the IP of the AD server as the auto-assigned primary DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your Domain Controller your primary DNS and DHCP server. Then, instead of using your router as these things, simply use it as the default gateway instead.

Comment: So, is it as simple as adding the DHCP role to my AD box?  If so, what do I use as DNS on the AD box?  I use Comcast as my internet provider.